$L^{\infty}(X)$ is weak-star sequentially complete
I'm trying to prove that if $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $L^{\infty}(X)$ with the $w^{*}$-topology is sequentially complete, but I am running into an issue at the last step.
Suppose that $(f_n)_n \subset L^{\infty}(X)$ is a $w^{*}$-Cauchy sequence.  Then by identifying $f_n \mapsto \varphi_n$ where: $$\varphi_n(g) = \int_{X} f_ng \: d\mu$$ via the duality $L^1(X)^{*} \cong L^{\infty}(X)$ (since the measure space is $\sigma$-finite) we then conclude that for each $g \in L^1(X)$, $|\varphi_n(g) - \varphi_m(g)| \longrightarrow 0$ by definition of being $w^{*}$-Cauchy.  However then $(\varphi_n(g))_n \subset \mathbb{C}$ converges to a number $\varphi(g) \in \mathbb{C}$ by completeness.
Define $\varphi: L^1(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\varphi(g) = \lim_n \varphi_n(g)$ .  Obviously $\varphi$ is linear, so if we just prove that $\varphi$ is bounded, then $\varphi \in L^1(X)^{*}$, so by the duality there exists a map $f \in L^{\infty}(X)$ such that: $$\varphi(g) = \int_{X}fg \: d\mu = \lim_n \varphi_n(g) =\lim_n \int_{X} f_ng \: d\mu \: \: \forall g \in L^1(\mu).$$  In particular then, $f_n \longrightarrow f$ in the $w^{*}$-topology on $L^{\infty}(X)$ by definition, which will finish the proof.
I'm having an issue actually proving that $\varphi$ is bounded however.  I know by the Closed Graph theorem that it suffices to consider a sequence $(g_k,\varphi(g_k)) \longrightarrow (0,\alpha) \in L^1(X) \times \mathbb{C}$ and prove that $\alpha = 0$.  Doing that, we see: $$|\alpha| = \lim_k |\varphi(g_k)| = \lim_k \lim_n |\varphi_n(g_k)| \leq \lim_k \sup_n \int_{X} |f_ng_k| \: d\mu$$ $$\leq \lim_k \sup_n \lVert f_n \lVert_{\infty} \lVert g_k \rVert_1.$$  Hence it suffices to know that $\sup_n \lVert f_n \rVert < \infty$, which is equivalent to proving the family of bounded linear maps $M_n: g \mapsto f_ng$ is pointwise bounded by the Uniform Boundedness Principle, however I haven't been able to show that this is true.
If I knew that $(\varphi_n) \subset V^{\circ}$ (the polar) for $V \subset L^1(X)$ an open neighborhood of $0$, then I also think I could prove $\varphi$ is bounded, as then $V^{\circ}$ is $w^{*}$-compact, and I at least get a convergent subsequence, but this also doesn't seem apparent to me.
What am I missing here to finish this argument?  $\textbf{A hint}$ would be great.

Hint: Apply the uniform boundedness principle to the family of operators $\{\varphi_n : n\in \mathbb N\}$.
